# check available space for iOS/android device in trigger.io app

Tags: trigger.io

in our trigger.io app we're using modules `file` and `camera`
and some users having problems with app because they don't have enough space available on their devices.

is there a way to check and notify a user that their device don't have available space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update to `v2.13` of the file module you can do:

```
forge.file.getStorageInformation(function (info) {
    forge.logging.log("Total space on device: " + info.total);
    forge.logging.log("Free space on device: " + info.free);
}, function (e) {
    // handle any errors
});
```

The success callback also includes information for app and cache directory sizes, for more information check out the [module documentation](https://trigger.io/modules/file/current/docs/index.html).